# Promise - nested function doesn't works

Tags: javascript, function

I'm wondering why the following code doesn't works, after all it is just nested function:

```js
var calculus = new Promise((resolve, reject) => (resolve) => resolve(3))

var calculus2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  () => resolve(4)
})

calculus.then((result) => console.log(result))
calculus2.then((result) => console.log(result))
```

any hint would be great,
thanks

Comment: A nested function doesn't automatically call itself, so the `resolve` is never called. (did you mean to immediately invoke it?)

Comment: Why is `calculus2` relevant here?

Comment: I think the problem is because you create a subfunction that never is called

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks for the spot, it is an another shot, I have updated my code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to invoke the nested function.

```js
var calculus = new Promise((resolve, reject) => ((resolve) => resolve(3))(resolve))

calculus.then((result) => console.log(result))
```

If you don't want to repeat `(resolve)` at the end, you can get rid of the parameter to the nested function.

```js
var calculus = new Promise((resolve, reject) => (() => resolve(3))())

calculus.then((result) => console.log(result))
```

In either case, there's not really much point to the nested function, you can just write:

```js
var calculus = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(3))

calculus.then((result) => console.log(result))
```

Comment: Or to avoid the `Promise` constructor anti-pattern: `var calculus = Promise.resolve(3)`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm willing to assume that the trivial function body is a simplification because that part is not relevant to the question.

Comment: That's fair. I'll leave the comment for OP, then.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: Barmar was faster with their answer, and reading it, I think I misinterpreted what you were asking a bit. However, I'm still going to post this as it might help clarify exactly what's going on in your example.

Your first line,

```
var calculus = new Promise((resolve, reject) => (resolve) => resolve(3))
```

Returns something comparable to an object like this (although it's quite different behind the scenes):

```
{
  then: function(callback) {
    callback(function (resolve) {
      resolve(3);
    });
  }
}
```

So to use this, you would want to do something like this:

```
calculus.then((resolver) => {
  resolver(function (value) {
    console.log(value); // 3
  });
});
```

I think what you're likely meaning to do is this:

```
const calculus = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(3));
calculus.then((result) => console.log(result))
```

Remember that `() => {}` is similar (though not quite the same) to `function() {}`, and `() => something` is like `function () { return something }`

So your original code is like this

```
var calculus = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  return function (resolve) {
    resolve(3)
  };
});
```

When you want

```
var calculus = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  resolve(3);
});
```